# Rss/Feedburner technical explanation?

Tags: rss, aggregate, feed, feedburner

the web is littered with non-technical explanations/tutorials on rss and feedburner.. and i've searched fruitlessly for a very-technical explanation/tutorial on rss and feedburner and feedblitz and how to build an aggregator etc.. so i was wondering does anyone have a link to a good technical-explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World Wide Web Consortium on RSS: http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html